# Alternative to global in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Global variables are generally considered bad practice unless absolutely necessary, so I am looking at alternative ways to achieve some functionality.

We are currently working on a CMS system in PHP, and wish to allow other developers to write modules easily for the CMS. We have defined a CMS class as follows:

```
class CMS
{
    public $version;
    public $sitename;
    public $siteurl;
    public $tbl_prefix;

    function __construct()
    { 

    }

    function RegisterModule()
    {

    }
}
```

Now, we would like to generate an instance of `CMS`, and make it accessible to the developer (and all modules and core files) through a variable: `$_cms`. Since we are not able to use constant variables for objects in PHP, and using a Singleton pattern provides clumsy syntax to access the instance (i.e. `CMS::GetInstance()->RegisterModule()`), is there any way to achieve what we want without defining a global variable containing an instance of `CMS`?

Ideally, we are looking for something like the following syntax:

`_cms->RegisterModule();` or `$_cms->RegisterModule();`, with the former being preferred.

Comment: So you basically want a global variable but don't want to call it a global variable? :-)

Comment: I would say I want a *constant* variable, rather than a global variable... ;-)

Comment: +1 cause it touches my intrests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Require plugins to be coded as classes, which either `extend` the `CMS` class or accept it as a parameter to their constructor. That's also known as Dependency Injection and is just about the cleanest interface you can get.

```
class MyPlugin {

    public function __construct(CMS $cms) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Requiring plugins to be classes also makes it really clean and easy to include them from your app, since they're self-contained and can easily follow specific naming and interface conventions.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and answer. What if I wanted to access the instance outside of a module class, though? For example in the view or controller?

Comment: If you include the view from inside a module class, it becomes part of the module class and can access the instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static class redirecting the method calls to the GetInstance()-Methods.

Is it neccessary to have an instance, or would it be possible to declare the CMS-class as static?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I am making seance  though let me put my view 
If i have such a problem I would use magic method __call() will be applicable to the files other developer will work on 
and it will look like 
in one of my code file

```
function __call($name,$params)
{
   if($name == 'RegisterModule')
   {
      $cms = myRegisty::get('cms');
      $cms->RegisterModule($params); 
   }

}
```

while at module registation it will look like

```
RegisterModule($params);
```

hope it helps :) I think your consern is about the syntax and want more keen looking code so this was my point